# Sentence starts with 'if'. Do i need to have a subject in the 2nd half of the sentence

Tags: conditionals, compound-subjects

What i mean:

If you exit the wizard go back to the touchscreen.

Is this correct?

Or do i have to say: If you exit the wizard, you can go back to the touchscreen.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: The first is ambiguous without the comma after *wizard*, since it could mean a flawed version of *If you exit, then the wizard will go back to the touchscreen*. While both are incomprehensible to me (since this is a new—to me—use of the word *touchscreen*), the second is at least grammatical, although how do you exit a wizard? Or perhaps you mean, *if you arrange for the wizard to leave, then you can go back to the touchscreen* (*to exit* does not mean *to cause to leave*). And it's better to have *then* in an *if/then* statement---this would reduce the ambiguity of the first example.

Comment: You have a Complex Sentence. The main clause is "go back to the touchscreen" and the dependent is "If you exit the wizard" In the main, the subject can be "understood" (you). And you need a comma between the clauses: "If you exit the wizard, (you) go back to the touchscreen." OR "Go back to the touchscreen if you exit the wizard." Here you are saying that if they exit the wizard you are instructing them to go back to the touchscreen with no option to do anything else. The wording in your second sentence, gives them an option to go back. It's a different meaning.

Comment: Both are fine.  In Sentence #1, you are using the *imperative* -- where you tell someone what to do.  Note, you may find http://ell.stackexchange.com/ helpful.

Comment: The body of this question does not match the title.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence may mean something else without a comma after 'wizard'. If you are instructing someone else to do something, you may use:

> Exit the wizard and then go back to the touchscreen.

The second sentence is correct.